# Update checkout sidebar after minicart update

Tags: magento2

I have an usecase where my customer has the top magento shopping cart icon available in the checkout.

[image]

The problem however is the fact that when someone updates the quantity on the minicart, the sidebar is not refreshed and thus wrong content is displayed there.

I already tried to extends this feature and found the minicart and a way to extend it but i cant find the right way to extend the "update QTY" event.

After that update i need to refresh the page. The sidebar should show other information but also the step of the checkout itself is dependent based on the content of the cart itself. So for a QTY of 2 there are extra fields on a specific step etc.

Hope someone can help

Best,
Pim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js the _updateItemQtyAfter method will fire the following trigger: $(document).trigger('ajax:updateCartItemQty').

```
$(document).on('ajax:updateItemQty', $.proxy(function () {
    // your stuff here...
}, this));
```

Or you can override and extend the method _updateItemQtyAfter in vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js.

The update button in the sidebar will fire the XHR /checkout/sidebar/updateItemQty/, so if above won't work you can try to do the following:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
   if (settings.url.indexOf('checkout/sidebar/updateItemQty') !== -1) {
       // your stuff here...
   }
});
```